# Multiple GridViews on one page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I am creating an application in C#. I have created a page in which there are 5 links. Each link opens a different page where there is a `GridView`.

Can I make all these grids on one page - i.e. when I click on `link1`, then only the grid corresponding to that link will appear on the page and when I click on `link2`, then only the grid for `link2` appears? Only the grid for the activated link should be visible and all other grids are hidden.

Can someone help me in how or where I should start?

Comment: What technology are you using? WPF or WinForms?

Comment: if this is using winforms i think you can use tabs, have one grid view per tab and have the link open up the right tab, one view, one grid at a time, perhaps?

Comment: Yes its possible. Where are u stuck right now? And what technology?

Comment: @RhysW i am not using winforms

Comment: ok, it generally helps if you mention that to start with ;)

Comment: i am just creating a web application and wanted to do this on a simple webpage.

Comment: @nawfal i am just creating a web application and can you please tell me how it can be done.

Comment: @user1852933 you need to show us where you are stuck and what you have tried so far! We don't just do answers for you or you don't learn anything!

Comment: @user1852933 please mention it in your question. Secondly, please read http://stackoverflow.com/faq this. You should tell us what have you tried and where you're stuck. SO doent help you by writing the code.

Comment: You could technically set this up with Partial views, then use a little bit of logic (perhaps a parameter passed in the link) to tell it wwhich partial view to display, tht way you can easily tweak it in the future to show more than one gridview if you wanted to.

Comment: @nawfal i have made the grids on different pages and has given the link of each page to its respective link. i just want to know how can i do it on the same page. i just want to know where to start from

Comment: @user1852933 Please please mention all these details in the question. You can edit your question. So that all the readers can follow it. Digging them up from comments wont be easier for ppl other than me.

Comment: @nawfal sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @user1852933 nothing to be sorry about, and there wasn't even a wee bit of inconvenience. You should always use "edit" feature of SO to make questions (and answers) better. It evokes more responses. And by editing it also pops your question high up in SO so that more users see it. As I said please read the faq as to how to ask a question in SO. In the current form, your question may be down voted or even closed. If you are only looking for a starter, then please mention it in question highlighting it..

Comment: In the link click event,enable the corresponding gridview to be visible and bind it.

Answer (score 3):

Since you specified webforms in your tag,the multiview control will do you wonders.Declare a multiview control with different views for each gridview.Hope this helps.

Usage

**MarkUp**

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">


    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1"  Text="Link1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
    <br>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" Text="Link2" OnClick="LinkButton2_Click">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton></br>

<asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">

    <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server" >

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>

    </asp:View>

      <asp:View ID="View2" runat="server">
      <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>
</asp:View>
</asp:MultiView>

</form>
```

**Code Behind**

```
    protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //retrieve data
        GridView1.DataBind();
        MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex=0;
     }


    protected void LinkButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         //retrieve data
        GridView1.DataBind();
        MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex=1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is a not such elegant way to do this as Abide Masaraure pointed. I suggest you to follow his answer.

But you also can put each gridview inside a different div, and set the attribute **"runat=server"** in these divs.

And for each link you can use an asp.net linkbutton (because this element has a default look of an html link).

Your aspx code will look simillar to this:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="lnkButton_1" text="Link 1" OnClick="lnkButton_1_Click"/>
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="lnkButton_2" text="Link 2" OnClick="lnkButton_2_Click"/>
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="lnkButton_3" text="Link 3" OnClick="lnkButton_3_Click"/>
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="lnkButton_4" text="Link 4" OnClick="lnkButton_4_Click"/>
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="lnkButton_5" text="Link 5" OnClick="lnkButton_5_Click"/>

<div runat="server" id="divGrid_1" Visible="false">
   <asp:GridView runat="server" id="grid_1"></asp:GridView>
</div>

<div runat="server" id="divGrid_2" Visible="false">
   <asp:GridView runat="server" id="grid_2"></asp:GridView>
</div>

<div runat="server" id="divGrid_3" Visible="false">
   <asp:GridView runat="server id="grid_3"></asp:GridView>
</div>

<div runat="server" id="divGrid_4" Visible="false">
   <asp:GridView runat="server" id="grid_4"></asp:GridView>
</div>

<div runat="server" id="divGrid_5" Visible="false">
   <asp:GridView runat="server" id="grid_5"></asp:GridView>
</div>
```

Your aspx.cs (codebehind) code will lool like this:

```
protected void lnkButton_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs E)
{
   divGrid_1.Visible = true;
   divGrid_2.Visible = false;
   divGrid_3.Visible = false;
   divGrid_4.Visible = false;
   divGrid_5.Visible = false;

   LoadGridView_1();
}
```

And for each link button event click you can set the visibility of the correspondent div to true and the other ones to false, and then you call the method that load the correspondent gridview.

I expect I've helped you.

Best regards.