# How to bind more than one gridview on single asp.net page?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

How to bind more than one gridview on single asp.net page,with edit, update and pagination. Must work independendly.

Comment: Is there a specific problem you are facing? This is not google.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211851/multiple-gridviews-on-one-page

Comment: i need to bind 5 grids on a same page, and give it edit/update, and each grid need to have an add and a delete button, to add and remove rows from the grid.